# Inferring number of strands from AWG -> mm

Tags: wire

If there is "16AWG" 1.34mm CSA wire, is it possible to figure out the strand count?

I am thinking it might be possible as AWG is about overall diameter. So 16AWG should have a diameter of 1.291, but if it's 1.34, does this imply a certain arrangement of a certain number of strands?

Comment: http://www.calmont.com/pdf/calmont-eng-wire-gauge.pdf